# How do I find the percentage of column sub-groups for every group?

Tags: r

I am working on a project in R that studies how frequently political parties in a country post migration-related content. One of my columns displays if migration is mentioned ('Yes' or 'No'). If migration is mentioned ('Yes'), I then specified which migrant group is mentioned.

I have found the percentage of migration-related posts out of all posts for every political party. I then tried to find the percentage of posts that mention specific migrant groups for every political party, such as 'Immigrants', 'Higher-paid workers', 'Migrant workers', and 'Domestic workers'. However, I can only do this for one group at a time, is there a faster way that I am missing?

1. This is how I found the percentage of migration-related posts out of all posts for every political party.

```
sg_percent_all <- sg_parties %>%
                  group_by(party_name) %>%
                  summarise(prop = (sum(migration == "Yes")/ n())*100)
```

2. I only found the percentage of posts that specifically mentions 'Immigrants' with this code, but I want to look at all four migrant groups. Is there a way to do this?

```
sg_parties %>%
  group_by(party_name) %>%
  summarise(prop = (sum(migrant_grp == "Immigrants")/ n())*100)
```

Comment: A minor suggestion: we do not have to use `sum(migrant_grp == "Immigrants") /n()`. `mean(migrant_grp == "Immigrants")` is a bit cleaner

Comment: We can only help so much without a proper reproducible example.
Please consider sharing the data and the desired output.
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to make a good R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suspect you may want to `table()` the immigrant groups

Comment: Welcome to SO, nae890! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly randomly), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your data, but, as other commenters mentioned, you'll get better help faster if you post some sample data.

You can try the below combination of `summarize` and `mutate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sg_parties <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~post_id,      ~party_name,  ~migration,   ~migrant_grp,
     1,             'party1',     'Yes',        'Immigrants',
     2,             'party2',     'No',         NA,
     3,             'party3',     'Yes',        'Migrant workers',
     4,             'party2',     'No',         NA,
     5,             'party1',     'Yes',        'Domestic workers',
     6,             'party2',     'Yes',        'Higher-paid workers',
     7,             'party2',     'No',         NA,
     8,             'party1',     'Yes',        'Migrant workers',
     9,             'party3',     'No',         NA,
     10,             'party1',     'Yes',        'Domestic workers'
  )

sg_parties %>% 
  filter(migration == 'Yes') %>% 
  summarize(
    n = n(),
    .by = c(party_name, migrant_grp)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    pct = n/sum(n),
    .by = c(party_name)
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   party_name migrant_grp             n   pct
#>   <chr>      <chr>               <int> <dbl>
#> 1 party1     Immigrants              1  0.25
#> 2 party3     Migrant workers         1  1   
#> 3 party1     Domestic workers        2  0.5 
#> 4 party2     Higher-paid workers     1  1   
#> 5 party1     Migrant workers         1  0.25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it helps. I'll try to create a more reproducible question next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sg_parties %>%
  filter(migration == "yes") %>%
  group_by(migrant_grp) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  migrant_grp             n   pct
  <chr>               <int> <dbl>
1 Higher-paid workers     1   0.2
2 Immigrants              2   0.4
3 Migrant workers         2   0.4
```

Toy data:

```
sg_parties <-
  data.frame(
    party = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)),
    migration = c(rep("yes",5), rep("no",5)),
    migrant_grp = c("Immigrants", "Migrant workers", "Immigrants", "Higher-paid workers", "Migrant workers"))
```